# BufferedConsole module not found

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm working in a React app with create-react-app and suddenly after installing react-charts-2 I started to get this error:

```
./node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'console' in '/my-app/node_modules/@jest/console/build'
```

I already tried to remove the react-charts-2 but the error still appears.

Any thoughts?

Node 6.9.0

Comment: I'm having this same problem too. It just occurred out of the blue after saving the component file I was working on.  I've deleted `node_modules` folder and re-installed everything but it's still happening.  I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this error due to auto import of a function from an incorrect library:

```
import each from 'jest-each' --  should be 'lodash' here
```

Removing this line fixed the issue.